# How to make vector line selectable?

Tags: java, swing, vector

I'm making a project for college, where I have to make my own primitive vector editor, and I have two questions:

1. Is it right to make vector line object by saving it's start point coordinates, end point coordinates, color and width of points, which it will consist of? `Point` is also my class, which is drawn on `JPanel`.
2. If it is right, how can I make this line selectable? The only thing I can think of is to check mouse coordinates to be inside of line width.

I also have a restriction not to use any standard functions for drawing lines, splines, etc.

Comment: Thank you. It's very pleasant to hear. Next time I won't do that (:

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Yes that's right. Or you could represent it in polar coordinates
2. the best thing to do is actually turn your line into an `Area`, which implements `Shape` and thus contains, which is the method you want. `Area` is a great abstraction because it can represent any shape but everything gets manipulated in the same way.

Comment: Thank you for directions. I'll read more about areas in java and try to immplement that.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Line2D Shape. To check selection you can gt stroked Shape from BasicStroke and check whether the stroked Shape contains clicked point.

Comment: Thank you. Line2d is really powerful, but unfortunately, I have a restriction not to use any standard line drawing functions.

Answer (score 0):

To Point 1: You also need to save the direction of the vector.

To Point 2: There are some frameworks like [GEF](http://www.eclipse.org/gef/) which do the job for you. Here you have to change your model. You need two classes: Point and Connection

Comment: If he saves the start point and the end point as distinct values (non-interchangeable) then he has all the information necessary for the direction.

Comment: Thank you for response. I looked briefly through GEF wiki and as I undertand, they are used to display a line between two points. But I forgot to mention that I have a restriction not to use standard functions of graphic libraries for drawing lines.

Answer (score 0):

1. You can use a class `Vector` if you have one with `start` and `end` `Point` for do it if you want.
2. You can have a method like that:

   ```
   private static Shape generateVector(Point start, Point end)
   ```

   In this method you can use one object of ´Area´ for **build** the vector, with `Line2D`.   Tree lines if you want an *arrow*.

   Or you can use a `GeneralPath` for build it.

For select a particular vector with the mouse, you can get the coordinates, with `getX()` and `getY()` on the `MouseEvent` and ask in the shape object with method `contains` and repaint with other color.

Good luck!

Comment: Thank you. I guess, I won't be allowed to use exactly this method (i'm not allowed to use standard line drawing functions), but i'll try to wtitr my own analogue of method contains for my lines (:

Comment: OK. I remember my courses of Graphics. We use some algorithms for drawing lines with points only.